# How do I open one particular external link in the same tab

Tags: mediawiki

This could be seen as an XY question. What I really want to do is pass a query argument to an internal link. (What I'm *really* trying to do is open the All Pages page with the hide redirects option set to true.)

But it seems that in order to do that, you have to use external link syntax with a full internal link. This results in a link with an arrow and that opens in a new tab. That is fine for real external links but this is actually an internal link using external link syntax.

I managed to hide the arrow by wrapping the link in a `div` with the css class `plainlinks` on it, which worked nicely, but the link still opens in a new tab.

I see that there is a global setting in `LocalSettings.php` called `$wgExternalLinkTarget` and it is currently set to `_blank` which is what allows external links to open in a new tab. This is ok, I do want real external links to open in a new tab, I just want to override that once for this one link if possible.

My link currently looks like this:

```html
<div class="plainlinks">
* [{{fullurl:Special%3AAllPages|hideredirects=1}} All Pages]
</div>
```

(Searching for this, there is no end of people wanting to open things in *new* tabs, but I find nothing for opening a link in the *same* tab.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript event listener that changes the `target` attribute if the URL has the same domain as your wiki's. This requires you to modify corresponding `MediaWiki:Skin.js` pages.

```js
// jQuery
$('body').on('click', 'a[href]', function(event) {
    const url = new URL(this.href);
    
    if (url.host === 'your.domain.here') {
        this.target = '_self';
    }
});

// Or vanilla JavaScript
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const element = event.target;
    
    if (!element.matches('a[href]')) {
        return;
    }
    
    const url = new URL(element.href);
    
    if (url.host === 'your.domain.here') {
        element.target = '_self';
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of mediawiki:Skin.js you could also use mediawiki:common.js